# How to compute the similarity between two text documents?

Tags: python, nlp

I am looking at working on an NLP project, in any programming language (though Python will be my preference).

I want to take two documents and determine how similar they are.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101569/algorithm-to-detect-similar-documents-in-python-script witch some nice answers

Answer (score 390, accepted):

The common way of doing this is to transform the documents into TF-IDF vectors and then compute the cosine similarity between them. Any textbook on information retrieval (IR) covers this. See esp. [*Introduction to Information Retrieval*](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/), which is free and available online.

#### Computing Pairwise Similarities

TF-IDF (and similar text transformations) are implemented in the Python packages [Gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) and [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer). In the latter package, computing cosine similarities is as easy as

```python
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = [open(f).read() for f in text_files]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)
# no need to normalize, since Vectorizer will return normalized tf-idf
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

or, if the documents are plain strings,

```python
>>> corpus = ["I'd like an apple", 
...           "An apple a day keeps the doctor away", 
...           "Never compare an apple to an orange", 
...           "I prefer scikit-learn to Orange", 
...           "The scikit-learn docs are Orange and Blue"]                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words="english")                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> tfidf = vect.fit_transform(corpus)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

though Gensim may have more options for this kind of task.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380394/simple-implementation-of-n-gram-tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity-in-python).

[Disclaimer: I was involved in the scikit-learn TF-IDF implementation.]

#### Interpreting the Results

From above, `pairwise_similarity` is a Scipy [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) that is square in shape, with the number of rows and columns equal to the number of documents in the corpus.

```python
>>> pairwise_similarity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 17 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

You can convert the sparse array to a NumPy array via `.toarray()` or `.A`:

```python
>>> pairwise_similarity.toarray()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
array([[1.        , 0.17668795, 0.27056873, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.17668795, 1.        , 0.15439436, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.27056873, 0.15439436, 1.        , 0.19635649, 0.16815247],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.19635649, 1.        , 0.54499756],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.16815247, 0.54499756, 1.        ]])
```

Let's say we want to find the document most similar to the final document, "The scikit-learn docs are Orange and Blue".  This document has index 4 in `corpus`.  You can find the index of the most similar document by **taking the argmax of that row, but first you'll need to mask the 1's, which represent the similarity of each document to itself**.  You can do the latter through `np.fill_diagonal()`, and the former through `np.nanargmax()`:

```python
>>> import numpy as np     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> arr = pairwise_similarity.toarray()     
>>> np.fill_diagonal(arr, np.nan)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> input_doc = "The scikit-learn docs are Orange and Blue"                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> input_idx = corpus.index(input_doc)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> input_idx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
4

>>> result_idx = np.nanargmax(arr[input_idx])                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> corpus[result_idx]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
'I prefer scikit-learn to Orange'
```

Note: the purpose of using a sparse matrix is to save (a substantial amount of space) for a large corpus & vocabulary.  Instead of converting to a NumPy array, you could do:

```
>>> n, _ = pairwise_similarity.shape                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> pairwise_similarity[np.arange(n), np.arange(n)] = -1.0
>>> pairwise_similarity[input_idx].argmax()                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
3
```

Comment: @larsmans Can you explain the array little bit if possible, how should I be reading this array. First two columns are similarity between First two sentences?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: at position (i,j), you find the similarity score between document i and document j. So, at position (0,2) is the similarity value between the first document and the third (using zero-based indexing), which is the same value that you find at (2,0), because cosine similarity is commutative.

Comment: If I were to average all of the values outside of the diagonal of 1's, would that be a sound way of getting a single score of how similar the four documents are to each other?  If not, is there a better way of determining overall similarity between multiple documents?

Comment: @user301752: you could take the element-wise mean of the tf-idf vectors (like k-means would do) with `X.mean(axis=0)`, then compute the average/maximum/median(∗) Euclidean distance from that mean. (∗) Pick whichever has your fancy.

Comment: thank you so much larsmans, this was very helpful, as you can tell by my question and your simple answer, this is new to me.

Comment: I do run the same code but in the resulting matrix i don't have any precision. It's like 0. 1. 0. etc. How can i fix that?

Comment: @curious: I updated the example code to the current scikit-learn API; you might want to try the new code.

Comment: @larsmans . What is this capital A and  capital T mean in terms of functionality?

Comment: @curious: In Scipy, `.A` transforms a sparse matrix to a dense one, for the purpose of printing it. `.T` means [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: BTW, if you're getting `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'`, try changing `tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)` to `tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(input='file').fit_transform(documents)`

Comment: 1 mean the two sentence is same(so diagonal is all 1). I know `TfidfVectorizer` transform a sentence to a float array(I know the float array means too), but can not understand why this array matrix_power itself equal to 1. I only know basic matrix operation, could you mind to explain it?

Comment: @FredFoo could you please take a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/39688927/python-tf-idf-predict-a-new-document-similarity/39689190#39689190 ?

Comment: @FredFoo  tf-idf requires a set of documents of some domain to which the documents to be compared belong to isn't it. Also, it is not always that good a similarity measure. Also, the OP just asked about similarity between two documents. I guess he just wants to compare two raw text files.

Comment: @FredFoo Does Tfidf consider synsets or even semantic similarity? Does it use any corpus?

Comment: Why is dot product sufficient and not the full similarity formula of a*b / llall *llbll

Comment: This didnt work for me. I have two vectors: v1=['akshit', 'stupid','bus','truck'] and v2=['human']
I used tfidf.fit_transform(v1,v2) on these two vectors and then I used the formulae: (tfidf * tfidf.T).A to find out the similarity. 
The result was 0.0.
So I checked with v2 = v1 = ['human'] and again the similarity was same as 0.0

Comment: `documents = [open(f) for f in text_files]` throws an error:
use this instead:
`documents = [open(f).read() for f in text_files]`

Comment: The matrix is not full. pairwise_similarity is not full. For n text files, there should be 2^n rows, and this is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: @Petar There are n² pairs between n objects (or n(n-1)/2 unique pairs, excluding self-pairs). `tfidf` is of size `len(documents)` × `TfidfVectorizer().get_feature_names_out().size`. The matrix multiplication `tfidf`×`tfidf`ᵀ is a square matrix of size `len(documents)`×`len(documents)`.

Answer (score 111):

Identical to @larsman, but with some preprocessing

```py
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

nltk.download('punkt') # if necessary...


stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

'''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]


print cosine_sim('a little bird', 'a little bird')
print cosine_sim('a little bird', 'a little bird chirps')
print cosine_sim('a little bird', 'a big dog barks')
```

Comment: @ Renaud, really good and clear answer! I have two doubts: I) what is the [0,1]  that you incorporate after tfidf * tfidf.T) and II) The inverse document frequency is formed from all the articles or just two (considering that you have more than 2)?

Comment: @AndresAzqueta [0,1] is the positions in the matrix for the similarity since two text inputs will create a 2x2 symmetrical matrix.

Comment: @Renaud, Thank you for your complete code. For those who encountered the error asking to nltk.download(), you can easily do nltk.download('punkt'). You do not need to download everything.

Comment: @Renaud I don't get a more fundamental problem. Which strings of text should `fit`, and which `transform`?

Comment: @JohnStrood I don't understand your question, sorry could you reformulate?

Comment: @Renaud I understand that `fit` computes IDFs for the vocabulary. Applying `transform` on a set of strings will compute tf-idfs before we finally apply cosine similarity. So, my question is, do we have to apply `fit` on the test string as well?

Comment: Wow, the tokenizer really alters the input. Any way of inspecting what actual text ends up being in the similarity computation?

Comment: @WurmD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352301/tfidfvectorizer-how-can-i-check-out-processed-tokens

Answer (score 77):

It's an old question, but I found this can be done easily with [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity). Once the document is read, a simple api `similarity` can be used to find the cosine similarity between the document vectors.

Start by installing the package and downloading the model:

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then use like so:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc1 = nlp(u'Hello hi there!')
doc2 = nlp(u'Hello hi there!')
doc3 = nlp(u'Hey whatsup?')

print (doc1.similarity(doc2)) # 0.999999954642
print (doc2.similarity(doc3)) # 0.699032527716
print (doc1.similarity(doc3)) # 0.699032527716
```

Comment: I wonder why the similarity between doc1 and doc2 is 0.999999954642 and not 1.0

Comment: @JordanBelf floating point numbers do wander around a bit in most languages - as they cannot have unlimited precision in digital representations. e.g. floating point operations on or producing irrational numbers always have tiny rounding errors creep in which then multiply. It's the downside of such a flexible representation in scale terms.

Comment: what is distance function that similarity method using in this case?

Comment: If you have issues finding "en" run the following pip install spacy && python -m spacy download en

Comment: @Cybernetic Take a look at [How is the .similarity method in SpaCy computed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304217/how-is-the-similarity-method-in-spacy-computed)

Comment: This is most likely the right answer for the OP had it been written after 2012.  This is really quick out of the box, just pip install space, and you get going in under 5 minutes.  There are other better, high performance answers out there, but state-of-the-art was not asked for.

Answer (score 38):

If you are looking for something very accurate, you need to use some better tool than tf-idf. [Universal sentence encoder](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11175) is one of the most accurate ones to find the similarity between any two pieces of text. Google provided pretrained models that you can use for your own application without a need to train from scratch anything. First, you have to install tensorflow and tensorflow-hub:

```
    pip install tensorflow
    pip install tensorflow_hub
```

The code below lets you convert any text to a fixed length vector representation and then you can use the dot product to find out the similarity between them

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1?tf-hub-format=compressed"

# Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
embed = hub.Module(module_url)

# sample text
messages = [
# Smartphones
"My phone is not good.",
"Your cellphone looks great.",

# Weather
"Will it snow tomorrow?",
"Recently a lot of hurricanes have hit the US",

# Food and health
"An apple a day, keeps the doctors away",
"Eating strawberries is healthy",
]

similarity_input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
similarity_message_encodings = embed(similarity_input_placeholder)
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    message_embeddings_ = session.run(similarity_message_encodings, feed_dict={similarity_input_placeholder: messages})

    corr = np.inner(message_embeddings_, message_embeddings_)
    print(corr)
    heatmap(messages, messages, corr)
```

and the code for plotting:

```py
def heatmap(x_labels, y_labels, values):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(values)

    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x_labels)))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(y_labels)))
    # ... and label them with the respective list entries
    ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
    ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels)

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", fontsize=10,
         rotation_mode="anchor")

    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    for i in range(len(y_labels)):
        for j in range(len(x_labels)):
            text = ax.text(j, i, "%.2f"%values[i, j],
                           ha="center", va="center", color="w", 
fontsize=6)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

the result would be:
[image: the similarity matrix between pairs of texts]

as you can see the most similarity is between texts with themselves and then with their close texts in meaning.

**IMPORTANT**: the first time you run the code it will be slow because it needs to download the model. if you want to prevent it from downloading the model again and use the local model you have to create a folder for cache and add it to the environment variable and then after the first time running use that path:

```
tf_hub_cache_dir = "universal_encoder_cached/"
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = tf_hub_cache_dir

# pointing to the folder inside cache dir, it will be unique on your system
module_url = tf_hub_cache_dir+"/d8fbeb5c580e50f975ef73e80bebba9654228449/"
embed = hub.Module(module_url)
```

More information: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2

Comment: hi thanks for this example encouraging me to try out TF - where should the object "np" come from?

Comment: UPD ok, I have installed numpy, matplotlib and also system TK Python binding for the plot and it works!!

Comment: Just in case (sorry for the lack of line breaks): import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Answer (score 17):

Generally a cosine similarity between two documents is used as a similarity measure of documents. In Java, you can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (if your collection is pretty large) or [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/) to do this. The basic concept would be to count the terms in every document and calculate the dot product of the term vectors. The libraries do provide several improvements over this general approach, e.g. using inverse document frequencies and calculating tf-idf vectors. If you are looking to do something copmlex, LingPipe also provides methods to calculate LSA similarity between documents which gives better results than cosine similarity. 
For Python, you can use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Note that there is no "LSA similarity". LSA is a method to reduce the dimensionality of a vector space (either to speed things up or to model topics rather than terms). Same similarity metrics that are used with BOW and tf-idf can be used with LSA (cosine similarity, euclidean similarity, BM25, …).

Answer (score 7):

For Syntactic Similarity 
There can be 3 easy ways of detecting similarity.

- Word2Vec
- Glove
- Tfidf or countvectorizer

For Semantic Similarity
One can use BERT Embedding and try a different word pooling strategies to get document embedding and then apply cosine similarity on document embedding.

An advanced methodology can use BERT SCORE to get similarity. 
[image: BERT SCORE]

Research Paper Link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09675

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little app to get you started...

```
import difflib as dl

a = file('file').read()
b = file('file1').read()

sim = dl.get_close_matches

s = 0
wa = a.split()
wb = b.split()

for i in wa:
    if sim(i, wb):
        s += 1

n = float(s) / float(len(wa))
print '%d%% similarity' % int(n * 100)
```

Comment: difflib is very slow if you going to work with large number of docs.

Answer (score 5):

To find sentence similarity with very less dataset and to get high accuracy you can use below python package which is using pre-trained BERT models,

```
pip install similar-sentences
```

Comment: I just tried that,
but it gives similarity of each sentence with the one main one, but is there any way to create all the sentence.txt training data as one class and get score on how much confidence it is getting matched to all the examplese?

Comment: yes you can, try .batch_predict(BatchFile,NumberOfPrediction) which will give output as Results.xls with Columns ['Sentence','Suggestion','Score']

Answer (score 4):

Creator of the [Simphile NLP](https://github.com/brianrisk/simphile) text similarity Python package here. Simphile contains several text similarity methods that are language agnostic and less CPU-intensive than language embeddings.

Install:

```
pip install simphile
```

Choose your favorite method.  This example shows three:

```
from simphile import jaccard_similarity, euclidian_similarity, compression_similarity

text_a = "I love dogs"
text_b = "I love cats"

print(f"Jaccard Similarity: {jaccard_similarity(text_a, text_b)}")
print(f"Euclidian Similarity: {euclidian_similarity(text_a, text_b)}")
print(f"Compression Similarity: {compression_similarity(text_a, text_b)}")
```

- **Compression Similairty** – leverages the pattern recognition of compression algorithms
- **Euclidian Similarity** – Treats text like points in multi-dimensional space and calculates their closeness
- **Jaccard Similairy** – Texts are more similar the more their words overlap

Answer (score 3):

If you are more interested in measuring semantic similarity of two pieces of text, I suggest take a look at [this gitlab project](https://gitlab.com/mysilver/semantic-text-similarity). You can run it as a server, there is also a pre-built model which you can use easily to measure the similarity of two pieces of text; even though it is mostly trained for measuring the similarity of two sentences, you can still use it in your case.It is written in java but you can run it as a RESTful service.

Another option also is [DKPro Similarity](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-similarity/) which is a library with various algorithm to measure the similarity of texts. However, it is also written in java.

code example:

```
// this similarity measure is defined in the dkpro.similarity.algorithms.lexical-asl package
// you need to add that to your .pom to make that example work
// there are some examples that should work out of the box in dkpro.similarity.example-gpl 
TextSimilarityMeasure measure = new WordNGramJaccardMeasure(3);    // Use word trigrams

String[] tokens1 = "This is a short example text .".split(" ");   
String[] tokens2 = "A short example text could look like that .".split(" ");

double score = measure.getSimilarity(tokens1, tokens2);

System.out.println("Similarity: " + score);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use sentencetransformer for this task
[link](https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html)

A simple example from sbert as below:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
# Two lists of sentences
sentences1 = ['The cat sits outside']
sentences2 = ['The dog plays in the garden']
#Compute embedding for both lists
embeddings1 = model.encode(sentences1, convert_to_tensor=True)
embeddings2 = model.encode(sentences2, convert_to_tensor=True)
#Compute cosine-similarities
cosine_scores = util.cos_sim(embeddings1, embeddings2)
#Output the pairs with their score
for i in range(len(sentences1)):
   print("{} \t\t {} \t\t Score: {:.4f}".format(sentences1[i], 
         sentences2[i], cosine_scores[i][i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this online service  for cosine document similarity http://www.scurtu.it/documentSimilarity.html

```
import urllib,urllib2
import json
API_URL="http://www.scurtu.it/apis/documentSimilarity"
inputDict={}
inputDict['doc1']='Document with some text'
inputDict['doc2']='Other document with some text'
params = urllib.urlencode(inputDict)    
f = urllib2.urlopen(API_URL, params)
response= f.read()
responseObject=json.loads(response)  
print responseObject
```

Comment: is the Api using Differential sequential Matcher ? If yes, then a Simple function in python would do the job 
____________________________________
 from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def isStringSimilar(a, b):
    ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    return ratio
______________________________

Answer (score 1):

I am combining the solutions from answers of @FredFoo and @Renaud. My solution is able to apply @Renaud's preprocessing on the text corpus of @FredFoo and then display pairwise similarities where the similarity is greater than 0. I ran this code on Windows by installing python and pip first. pip is installed as part of python but you may have to explicitly do it by re-running the installation package, choosing modify and then choosing pip. I use the command line to execute my python code saved in a file "similarity.py". I had to execute the following commands:

```
>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\_location_of_python_lib_
>python -m pip install sklearn
>python -m pip install nltk
>py similarity.py
```

The code for similarity.py is as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import nltk, string
import numpy as np
nltk.download('punkt') # if necessary...

stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

corpus = ["I'd like an apple", 
           "An apple a day keeps the doctor away", 
           "Never compare an apple to an orange", 
           "I prefer scikit-learn to Orange", 
           "The scikit-learn docs are Orange and Blue"]  

vect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(corpus)   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T

#view the pairwise similarities 
print(pairwise_similarity)

#check how a string is normalized
print(normalize("The scikit-learn docs are Orange and Blue"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute the similarity between two text documents, you can use the Word2Vec model from the Gensim library. This model captures semantic relationships between words and can be utilized to calculate the similarity between sentences. Here's your code along with some explanations:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
import numpy as np

# Define the calculate_similarity function
def calculate_similarity(sentence1, sentence2):
    # Tokenize the sentences
    tokens1 = simple_preprocess(sentence1)
    tokens2 = simple_preprocess(sentence2)

    # Load or train a Word2Vec model
    # Here, we'll create a simple model for demonstration purposes
    sentences = [tokens1, tokens2]
    model = Word2Vec(sentences, vector_size=100, window=5, min_count=1, sg=0)

    # Calculate the vector representation for each sentence
    vector1 = np.mean([model.wv[token] for token in tokens1], axis=0)
    vector2 = np.mean([model.wv[token] for token in tokens2], axis=0)

    # Calculate cosine similarity
    similarity = np.dot(vector1, vector2) / (np.linalg.norm(vector1) * np.linalg.norm(vector2))
    return similarity

# Example usage
sentence1 = "This is the first document."
sentence2 = "This document is the second document."
similarity_score = calculate_similarity(sentence1, sentence2)
print("Similarity score:", similarity_score)
```