# Python Scikit-learn: Empty Vocabulary in TF-IDF

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am using the code given in most up-voted answer to this question ([Similarity between two text documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents)) to calculate TF-IDF between documents. However, I observe that when I run the code WITHOUT specifying a custom value of `min_df` (1, in the code), then if two documents are completely different (such that there is no common word in them), instead of receiving a TF-IDF value of 0, I get the following error:

`ValueError: empty vocabulary; training set may have contained only stop words or min_df (resp. max_df) may be too high (resp. too low).`

Can somebody tell me how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I think that instead of "a TF-IDF value of 0" but you mean "a cosine similarity of 0". TF-IDF values are vectors with size `n_features == len(vectorizer.vocabulary_)`, one vector for each document in the pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (in sklearn <= 0.13) `min_df` is set to `min_df=2` which means that each word must at least occur in 2 different documents from the corpus to be included in the vectorizer's vocabulary. While this is a reasonable choice for large corporas, it's too restrictive to get anything included in a toy dataset with just a couple of sentences, hence the error message you get which I find pretty explicit. The `min_df=2` default has been changed to `min_df=1` in the development branch of scikit-learn to be less confusing to new users who try the library with default parameter value on toy datasets.