# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, attributeerror, scikit-learn

I am trying to run an example provided in stack overflow which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents).

I have copied the code here again:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
text_files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
documents = [open(f) for f in text_files]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)
# no need to normalize, since Vectorizer will return normalized tf-idf
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

The only thing I added is this line:

```
text_files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
```

when I run the code I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 195, in <lambda>
return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

the `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are input text files. Am I using a wrong format for `text_files`? what is the reason for this error and how can I fix that? I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This is most annoying because I have seen the exact same (wrong) code elsewhere.  You can fix one copy, but you wonder, how many places on the internet does this remain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`open(f)` is a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object, that's why it fails.

Try changing

```
documents = [open(f) for f in text_files]
```

to

```
documents = [open(f).read() for f in text_files]
```

Comment: (Which instead returns a...)