# Approach to Sentence similarity algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to implement a sentence similarity algorithm. Is it possible to implement it using sequence prediction algorithm? If it is possible what kind of approach should i go forward with or is there any other method which is more suitable for sentence similarity algorithm ,please share your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to treat your sentences as separate documents and then use traditional approach for finding similarity between documents. It was answered here using sklearn:
[Similarity between two text documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents)
If you want, you could try and implement the same code in tensorflow.

I also strongly recommend to read this answer, which covers more sophisticated approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15173821/3633250

Comment: Thanks for the info Maxim .One more question though on the first link you have mentioned ,are the solutions mentioned similar to word2vec conversion and should I drop the idea of using sequence prediction .

Comment: @Aniruddh sorry, I didn't follow your second question - in your original question there is nothing about sequence prediction.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `Doc2Vec`. Each sentence (*document*) is mapped to an n-dimensional space. To find the most similar *document*,

`model.most_similar(“documentID”)`

[Reference](https://medium.com/@klintcho/doc2vec-tutorial-using-gensim-ab3ac03d3a1#.wcfwfxk1s)