# How to use glove pretrained vectors to find similarity between two words and later in two documnets?

Tags: python, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find cosine similarity between two documents. To start with, I am trying to use it to find similarities between two words. I want to load the pretrained vectors and then use them to do the given task. There is not enough documentation of glove-python package. Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction or if I should use some other package.
I am trying to find similarities between sentences like:

For eg. - The man walked his dog in the park 
        - A poodle was travelling through a field with her owner

Comment: There is exactly what you want here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am inclined towards GLOVE or Word2vec so that it can also take into account the grammar and synonyms into account. For eg.
-          The man walked his dog in the park
-          A poodle was travelling through a field with her owner

Comment: Maybe you should explain more your project because right now I think it's to open to get an interesting answer.

Comment: here is overview (I cant see promised python code though but still a useful read) : https://medium.com/@adriensieg/text-similarities-da019229c894