# Which hashing algorithm should I use to compare pieces of text?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, text-processing, similarity

I have a large number of pieces of text which I need to compare between themselves to check whether or not they are similar. Each piece is about 10000 words long.
Hence I'll pre-calculate a hash of each one and compare hashes.

The question is, which hash algorithm would be better for that? md5? sha1? sha256? Or perhaps base64?
Or maybe it doesn't even really matter?

I'm aware that even single whitespace can change the value of a hash, that's ok with me.

Comment: What have you tried? A search for "text similarity" on google provides quite a lot of results...

Comment: Hashing will only speed the process of finding *exact duplicates*. As you say, any minor change will produce a different hash code. Are you trying to find exact duplicates? If you're looking for similarity (rearranged paragraphs, a few changed words, slightly varying sentence structure, etc.), you'll need a much more involved algorithm.

Comment: @JimMischel, learn to read.

Comment: Rudeness is not required. *Your requirements are unclear.* You said that you want to "check whether or not they similar." My point is that "similar" is not necessarily "exact duplicate." I did acknowledge your comment about being okay with whitespace changing the value of a hash. You need to clarify whether you're looking for similarity (i.e. this text is somewhat like that other text) or *exact duplicate*.

Comment: @JimMischel, required.

Answer (score 1):

**Hashes basically only gives you one piece of information: different hashes = different strings. If this is all you need, then any regular hash will do because they're more or less equally sensitive to changes in text.**

## Everything That Isn't A Direct Answer

Now onto the problems that stopped people from giving you a fair answer. Because you don't say exactly what you need, everyone is forced to make assumptions about your problem or just cannot give a proper answer.

If you just wanted confirmed differences and are okay with unconfirmed differences (since different strings can have the same hash a.k.a hash collisions), then any regular hashcode is fine. But because you said check for similarity, it's implied you want one of two things.

### Similarity As Equality

If you need equality, there is no hashing algorithm that can guarantee equality. Two different strings can generate the same hash. If you need equality checks to be faster, you'd have to use tricks like compression or combining chars into 64 bit integers.

### Similarity As Pseudo-Equality

If you're using similarity to filter out obviously different strings then you're better off just creating your own algorithm to quickly filter out different strings. A universal problem is that hashes are made to be irreversible and this typically involves a lot of mathematical computations.

You probably wanted hashes because they are a one-time conversion of text into a single integer and are highly sensitive to changes but there are better algorithms for that. Chaos theory can help but even just `result = result ** (i * text[i])` is pretty good at being change sensitive.

But because of your specific use case, using the string to generate a comparable number may not even be the best idea. With your text being that big, it's probably more efficient to just sample 5 character per 1000 characters. (ex. With these two numbers: "8149154147..." and "4396666666...", just comparing the first number is faster than hashing.)

Far more optimal solutions can exist if you know your data set. If it's human text, comparing the first paragraph is all you need. I have never in my life seen two text that have the same starting paragraph. If the initial text are often the same because the texts are all based on a prompt, you can use the last paragraph. If the characters or words are random, then it's practically impossible for the first 10 to be the same.

## tl;dr:

Hashes are non-representative and irreversible so therefore mathematically complex. Create your own "hash" but better yet, use heuristics.

P.S. - I know this is an age old post and I'm necroing this but I think it was a mostly reasonable question that deserves an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use zlib.crc32 then do textual compare of texts with matching hashes to make sure.

Comment: The above would be a check for equality - including spaces, punctuation etc. I chose it because I have used it to compare millions of sequences of 4K bytes before to see if I chanced on even one case of  a single bit flip not being caught by the CRC - After getting a statistical value of how unlikely it would be of course.

Comment: yes, how do you know it's better than base64, md5, sha1, etc, for this task?

Comment: I don't know it is better. I think it will suffice however.

Answer (score 0):

### When does hashing work?

What hashing does is reduce search space so that equivalent items can be found more quickly.  It works whenever there is a reliable way to produce a single [canonical value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form) for all members of an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

### Selecting a unique value among equivalent strings

Before hashing, the strings need to be converted to a canonical value (one unique representation among all equivalent strings).

> I'm aware that even a single whitespace can change the value of a
>   hash, that's ok with me.

For your application, here is possible canonicalizing function that just removes whitespace:

```
>>> def canonical(s):
        return ''.join([c for c in s if not c.isspace()])

>>> s = 'the   quick\nbrown\tfox jumped'
>>> t = '  the\tquick   brown  fox  jumped'
>>> canonical(s)
'thequickbrownfoxjumped'
>>> canonical(t)
'thequickbrownfoxjumped'
```

### Applying a hash function

A [*sha256()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) is fast and has almost no chance of a false positive.

In Python 2, you can compute the sha256 directly from a string.  However, in Python 3, the string must first be encoded into bytes:

```
>>> from hashlib import sha256
>>> sha256(canonical(s).encode()).hexdigest()
'2c31c202821431b015cb800ab6315289884e87f1ed023abc876915685c620919'
>>> sha256(canonical(t).encode()).hexdigest()
'2c31c202821431b015cb800ab6315289884e87f1ed023abc876915685c620919'
```

### When won't hashing work?

If you just want to group by [text similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents), hashing doesn't work as well because there isn't a straight-forward way to choose a representative element and because similarity is isn't a [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) (*a* is close to *b* and *b* is close to *c* doesn't imply that *a* is close to *c*).