# Python: is this an inefficient way to compare and sort lists of strings?

Tags: python, performance, nltk, string-comparison, cosine-similarity

I have two lists of strings, A and B. For each string in A, I'd like to compare it to every string in B and select the most similar match. The comparison function that I'm using is a custom cosine similarity measure that [I found on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents). Here is how it works:

```
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
nltk.download('punkt')

stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]
```

My issue is that if I have somewhat long lists (500-1000 items), and the execution starts to take five or ten minutes. Here's an example using some dummy text:

```
import requests    
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/WalkerHarrison/940c005aa23386a69282f373f6160221/raw/6537d999b9e39d62df3784d2d847d4a6b2602876/sample.txt'
sample = requests.get(url).text
A, B = sample[:int(len(sample)/2)], sample[int(len(sample)/2):]
A, B = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(A)]*100))), list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(B)]*100)))
```

Now that I have two lists, each with ~500 strings (of 100 characters each), I compute the similarities and take the top one. This is done by taking a string from A, iterating through B, sorting by cosine_sim score, and then taking the last element, and then repeating for all elements in A:

```
matches = [(a, list(sorted([[b, cosine_sim(a, b)] 
                            for b in B], key=lambda x: x[1]))[-1])
           for a in A]
```

The output is a list of matches where each item contains both strings and also their calculated similarity score. That final line took 7 minutes to run though. I'm wondering if there are inefficiencies in my process that are slowing it down or if there's just a lot to compute (500*500 = 250,000 comparisons, plus sorting for the best 500 times)?

Comment: Are you computing tfidf for each pair of documents? Aside from being extremely inefficient, that doesn't make sense, you should compute TFidf across the whole corpus, **then do pairwise similarity with cosine**

Comment: Also, are you just arbitrarily chunking your text-file into 100-length chunks?

Comment: So to your first question, I was thinking that since I was comparing each individual sentence to one an other, TFidf would be applied individually. But maybe I can isolate pairwise sentences after?

To your second Q, yes I was just chunking it arbitrarily, but that was just to create an example list of strings. For the actual data I have true sentences that have been divided correctly.

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. TFIDF works across a whole corpus, that is what it is designed to do. That's what makes it effective. Calculating Tfidf for each pair of documents *and then calculating cosine similarity based on that tfidf*, and *then comparing distances*, isn't really valid. And it's extremely inefficient.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you know if there's a way to make sentence-to-sentence comparisons after running TFIDF on both texts in their entirety, or do I need to find a new way to compare (short) strings?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. First of all, you should be using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances` with `metric=cosine`, this will be faster than anything you cook up yourself in vanilla python...

Comment: I've added an answer giving you the gist of the approach I would take here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue probably is that you are computing tfidf for every pair of documents (document here merely meaning your unit of text - this could be a tweet, a sentence, a scientific paper, or a book). Also, you shouldn't cook up your own similarity measure if it already exists. Finally, `sklearn` has a `pairwise_distance` routine that does what you want and is optimized. Putting this all together, here is a sample script:

```
import requests
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/WalkerHarrison/940c005aa23386a69282f373f6160221/raw/6537d999b9e39d62df3784d2d847d4a6b2602876/sample.txt'
sample = requests.get(url).text.split('\n\n') # I'm splitting the document by "paragraphs" since it is unclear what you actually want

stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')


doc_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(sample)
distances = pairwise_distances(doc_vectors, metric='cosine')


row_idx = list(enumerate(distances.argmax(axis=1)))
sorted_pairs = sorted(row_idx, key= lambda x: distances[x[0], x[1]], reverse=True)

# most similar documents:

i1, i2 = sorted_pairs[0] # index of most similar pair

print(sample[i1])
print("=="*50)
print(sample[i2])
```

There were 99 documents in my `sample` list, and this ran pretty much instantaneously after the download was complete. Also, the output:

> Art party taxidermy locavore 3 wolf moon occupy. Tote bag twee tacos
>   listicle, butcher single-origin coffee raclette gentrify raw denim
>   helvetica kale chips shaman williamsburg man braid. Poke normcore lomo
>   health goth waistcoat kogi. Af next level banh mi, deep v locavore
>   asymmetrical snackwave chillwave. Subway tile viral flexitarian pok
>   pok vegan, cardigan health goth venmo artisan. Iceland next level twee
>   adaptogen, dreamcatcher paleo lyft. Selfies shoreditch microdosing
>   vape, knausgaard hot chicken pitchfork typewriter polaroid lyft
>   skateboard ethical distillery. Farm-to-table blue bottle yr artisan
>   wolf try-hard vegan paleo knausgaard deep v salvia ugh offal
>   snackwave. Succulents taxidermy cornhole wayfarers butcher, street art
>   polaroid jean shorts williamsburg la croix tumblr raw denim. Hot
>   chicken health goth taiyaki truffaut pop-up iceland shoreditch
>   fingerstache.

====================================================================================================

> Organic microdosing keytar thundercats chambray, cray raclette. Seitan
>   irony raclette chia, cornhole YOLO stumptown. Gluten-free palo santo
>   beard chia. Whatever bushwick stumptown seitan cred quinoa. Small
>   batch selfies portland, cardigan you probably haven't heard of them
>   shabby chic yr four dollar toast flexitarian palo santo beard offal
>   migas. Kinfolk pour-over glossier, hammock poutine pinterest coloring
>   book kitsch adaptogen wayfarers +1 tattooed lomo yuccie vice. Plaid
>   fixie portland, letterpress knausgaard sartorial live-edge. Austin
>   adaptogen YOLO cloud bread wayfarers cliche hammock banjo. Sustainable
>   organic air plant mustache.

Comment: Thanks for this, starting to make more sense now. So if I replace `'\n\n'` with `'.'` I should get the same idea applied to sentences as opposed to paragraphs?

Comment: @WalkerHarrison well, only if `.` is a correct sentence delimiter, which is not always the case. But yes, basically.

Comment: so last thing (I think): since we're using `argmax` I think we're actually finding the least similar docs. So we could either take the `argmin` or the `argmax` of the complement. And one last twist—since each doc is it's own closest comparison, cells that are 0 (or 1 for complement) need to be changed or ignored, I think.