# FileNotFoundError in Python during Arabic text analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found

I have a folder has 150 Arabic text files. I want to find the similarities between each other.
how can I do that?
I tried what explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = [open(f) for f in text_files]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)
# no need to normalize, since Vectorizer will return normalized tf-idf
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

but I faced a problem with declaring documents.
I modified it like:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

text_files= r"C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\corpora\modified Corpora\Training set\5K\ST"
for f in text_files:
    documents= open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)
# no need to normalize, since Vectorizer will return normalized tf-idf
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

but it appears this error:

```
documents= open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'
```

any solution?

Edit:

I tried this also:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

import os

text_files= os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\corpora\modified Corpora\Training set\5K\ST")

documents= []
for f in text_files:
    file= open(f, 'r', 'utf-8-sig')
    documents.append(file.read())
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)
# no need to normalize, since Vectorizer will return normalized tf-idf
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

and it occurred this error:

```
file= open(f, 'r', 'utf-8-sig')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: There is no problem with comparison of Arabic texts, but with the path to your file. Is the `ST` really a text file? It seems more like a folder.

Comment: Moreover, your for cycle now loops over string characters, which means that it takes only one letter from the string `text_files` in the `open()` command. You could try `documents = open(text_files, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()` if `text_files` is really apath to existing file.

Comment: ST is a folder contains text files that I want to compare them to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a problem with the comparison of Arabic texts. You have trouble loading the documents into Python.

If `ST` is a folder, you need to get the list of all the files inside the folder:

```
import os
inputDir = r'your/path/here'
text_files = os.listdir(inputDir)

documents = []
for f in text_files:
    file = open(os.path.join(inputDir, f), 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
    documents.append(file.read())
```

The current version of your code also keeps only the last document from the loop, not all of them. However, that is another issue for another question.

Comment: so how can I modify the code to work with multiple files inside the folder? it showed this error when I am trying to run file= open(f, 'r', 'utf-8-sig')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str).

Comment: Did you try the `os.listdir()` function as I have suggested?

Comment: You have to keep the order of the parameters or you need to use their names. The third parameter in the function `open()` is called `buffering` and expects integers. You probably meant the `encoding` parameter?

Comment: yes, encoding parameter and the order is correct I use it many times like this order.

Comment: You can check the parameters of `open()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). The first parameter is called `file`, second `mode`, third `buffering` and fourth `encoding`. Therefore you need to either use the parameter `encoding` on the fourth position or explicitly write `encoding = 'utf-8-sig'`. Please check the updated example in my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. this error is appeared when I am trying to run you editing. text_files = os.listdir(inputDir) TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not list

Comment: thanks for your help. this error is appeared when I am trying to run you editing. text_files = os.listdir(inputDir) TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not list

Comment: I suppose you define the inputDir as `inputDir = r"C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\corpora\modified Corpora\Training set\5K\ST"`?

Comment: I think it worked, and this is one of the results (0, 60) 0.299395929151. Do you know what is mean? thanks for your help.

Comment: tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(documents)

pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T

print(pairwise_similarity) #this is the rest of the code