# Tfidfvectorizer - How can I check out processed tokens?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

How can I check the strings tokenized inside `TfidfVertorizer()`?  If I don't pass anything in the arguments, `TfidfVertorizer()` will tokenize the string with some pre-defined methods. I want to observe how it tokenizes strings so that I can more easily tune my model.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ['This is the first document.',
          'This document is the second document.',
          'And this is the third one.',
          'Is this the first document?']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

I want something like this:

```
>>>vectorizer.get_processed_tokens()
[['this', 'is', 'first', 'document'],
 ['this', 'document', 'is', 'second', 'document'],
 ['this', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'one'],
 ['is', 'this', 'the', 'first', 'document']]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`build_tokenizer()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.build_tokenizer) would exactly serve this purpose.

Try this!

```
tokenizer = lambda docs: [vectorizer.build_tokenizer()(doc) for doc in docs]

tokenizer(corpus)
```

Output:

```
[['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document'],
 ['This', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document'],
 ['And', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'one'],
 ['Is', 'this', 'the', 'first', 'document']]
```

​One liner solution would be

```
list(map(vectorizer.build_tokenizer(),corpus))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a built in sklearn function to get your output in that format but I'm pretty sure a fitted TfidfVectorizer instance has a `vocabulary_` attribute that returns a dictionary of the mapping of terms to feature indices. Read more [here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

A combination of that and the output of the `get_feature_names` method should be able to do this for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be syntactically correct (doing this on memory), but its the general idea:

```
Y = X.to_array()
Vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
fake_corpus = []
for doc in Y:
    l = [Vocab[word_index] for word_index in doc]
    fake_corpus.append(l)
```

With Y you have the indexs of your words for each doc in the corpus, with vocab you have the words a given index corresponds too, so you basically just need to combine them.