# NLTK Library python for text similarity checking

Tags: python

Can any one give a particular git repository for text similarity checking code using python.
Or
Can help in making the program of text similarity checking using python.

Comment: That might be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/how-to-compute-the-similarity-between-two-text-documents

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Levenshtein Distance to calculate the similarity of 2 words.
`FuzzyWuzzy`is a good library that makes use of this algorithm.

Example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

fuzz.ratio("Catherine M Gitau", "Catherine Gitau")
```

Result:

```
#91
```

So between those two strings there is a 91% similarity.

You can read more about this topic here:

- [FuzzyWuzzy](https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python-68f240d910fe)
- [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)