# Text Analytics :Field Failure Analysis

Tags: nlp, analytics, text-mining, named-entity-recognition

In the log data (specific to `automotive industry`) I have two files

- ***Inspection log***: This data has Vehicle test data before sending to market with attributes  `part-name(vehicle part)`, `Repairer Comments`
- ***Warranty data log***: This data is claim data after selling it to customer with attributes `part-name`, `dealer comments about defect`

Now we need to find similarity between `inspection logs` and `warranty logs` so that we are able to say if a vehicle has specific problem in inspection stage there is fair chance it will have other problem from warranty.

Also, Part name inspection data  may not be written same in warranty data like if i have `frontwheelbreakdown` it may be referred as `FWB` in short.

How do I go ahead with the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to detect similar documents in python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101569/algorithm-to-detect-similar-documents-in-python-script)

Comment: Look at cosine similarity. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101569/algorithm-to-detect-similar-documents-in-python-script) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/similarity-between-two-text-documents)